# Как вывести слова из Объекта которые есть в массиве на Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Есть JSON объект, нужно в html страницу вывести все слова из массива, как сделать лучше?

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fetch Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <div class="card__container">
      <div class="card__item" v-for="(item, idx) in original" :key="item.id">
        <div class="card__front">
          <div class="card__header">
            <span>{{ item.id }}</span>
            <span>{{ item.en.topic }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="card__body">
            <div class="card__words">
              <span> {{ item.en.words }} </span>  //сюда нужно вывести слова, как сделать?

            </div>
            <div class="card__img">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="card">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Fetch data",
      original: [{
      "id": 261,
      "en": {
        "topic": "Substances & Materials",
        "words": [
          "denim",
          "a denim jacket",
          "Denim is always in fashion"
        ]
      },
      "uk": {
        "тема": "Речовини та матеріали",
        "слова": [
          "джинс",
          "джинсова куртка",
          "Джинс завжди в моді"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "en": {
        "topic": "Eating",
        "words": [
          "a vitamin",
          "vitamin tablets",
          "Oranges contain vitamin C"
        ]
      },
      "uk": {
        "тема": "Їжа",
        "слова": [
          "вітамін",
          "вітаміни в таблетках",
          "Апельсини містять вітамін C"
        ]
      }
    },]
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#container")
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `v-for` - это агалогия `for` только для тегов

```
<span v-for="(word, index) in item.en.words" :key="index"> {{ word }} </span>
```